# Transform JavaScript Array, create tabular view

Tags: javascript, arrays, transform, tabular

I've searched through similar questions and tried to solve the issue on my own, but my programming skills are weak.

I have an array like:

```
[{"city": "Amsterdam", "year": "2013", "amount": "450"},
 {"city": "Rotterdam", "year": "2013", "amount": "620"},
 {"city": "Geneva",    "year": "2014", "amount": "530"},
 {"city": "Rotterdam", "year": "2015", "amount": "350"}]
```

and I want to transform it using "city" and "year" to get "amounts". E.g. Rotterdam:[620,N/A,350]. "N/A" because value for year 2014 is missing. 
I was checking map function etc. but my skills are to weak. 
In the end I want to create a tabular view with years (horizontal) and cities (vertical).
Please advice. Thanks

Comment: Show us some code you tried.

Comment: try see about [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function

Comment: @mplungjan You have a falcon eye, but I have edited the post already and corrected that. The edit has not been yet approved.

Comment: @ mplugjan: it was just a copy-paste error. array is valid. checked with json validator. thanks though.

Comment: @cezar I know - I already approved to give you the rep, I fail to see why we need another approver when I could just have improved and saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is programming skills but algorithm skills. Here is a code doing what you want:

```js
var amounts = [{"city": "Amsterdam", "year": "2013", "amount": "450"},{"city": "Rotterdam", "year": "2013", "amount": "620"},{"city": "Geneva", "year": "2014", "amount": "530"},{"city": "Rotterdam", "year": "2015", "amount": "350"}],
    formattedAmounts = {}
;
             
for (var i = 0; i < amounts.length; i++) {
    var amount = amounts[i];
  
    if (undefined === formattedAmounts[amount.city]) {
        formattedAmounts[amount.city] = {};
    }

    formattedAmounts[amount.city][amount.year] = amount.amount;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(formattedAmounts));
alert(JSON.stringify(formattedAmounts));

function getCityAmount(city) {
    var years = [2013, 2014, 2015],
        cityAmounts = []
    ;

    for (var i = 0; i < years.length; i++) {
        cityAmounts.push(
            formattedAmounts[city] && formattedAmounts[city][years[i]]
                ?  formattedAmounts[city][years[i]]
                : 'N/A'
        );
    }

    return cityAmounts;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(getCityAmount('Amsterdam')));
alert(JSON.stringify(getCityAmount('Amsterdam')));

function getCitiesAmounts() {
    var citiesAmounts = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < amounts.length; i++) {
        citiesAmounts.push(getCityAmount(amounts[i].city));
    }

    return citiesAmounts;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(getCitiesAmounts()));
alert(JSON.stringify(getCitiesAmounts()));
```

Comment: I updated the snippet to have the format you asked for.

Comment: thanks very much. It works fine but how do I get "NA" , when combination is missing ? I would like to get same number of amounts as number of months, even though value for month is missing.

Comment: @ Gnucki: sorry for coming back to you again but I didn't manage to get an array for all cities.

Comment: @ Gnucki: sorry for coming back to you again but I didn't manage to get an array for all cities. First I get a distinct list of cities . Done. But I didn't manage to get something like var xyz =[[a,b,c,d], [e,f,g,h]....] . sorted according to sorted list of cities. I tried to alter you code. Thanks

Comment: What you are asking to me is not clear. Show me a real example of what you want. You can add it to your question and post a comment when it is done.

Comment: Ok, to put it short: how can I use function getCityAmount() on all cities and return an array like  varAr =[[a,b,c],[d,e,f],...]   / a , b ,c are results from first city , d, e, f  are results from second city etc. Giving a sorted list of cities. Thank you.

Comment: Use `getCitiesAmounts`. You should be more confident in yourself and try to develop this kind of "easy" algorithm if you want to progress in your code. You certainly can find some resources on basic programming and algorithmic in javascript if you need some help.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've tried all sort of things . I'm trying hard to learn JS